# Failed to find Content Provider in API 30

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

**UPDATE:** I have to completely change my question since I found more details related to my problem.

The problem: My app that resolves Content Provider doesn't work in Emulator with API 30. The error:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Failed to find provider com.a52.datafeeder01.MyProvider for user 0; expected to find a valid ContentProvider for this authority
```

If I use APIs 26,27,28 and 29 then there is **no problem**.

AndroidManifest.xml in app with ContentProvider:

```
<manifest>
    <permission
        android:name="MyProvider._READ_PERMISSION"
        android:protectionLevel="normal" />
    <application>
        <activity>
        ...
        </activity>
        <provider android:name=".MyProvider"
            android:authorities="com.a52.datafeeder01.MyProvider"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:readPermission="MyProvider._READ_PERMISSION"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

AndroidManifest.xml in client app :

```
<manifest>
...
    <uses-permission android:name="MyProvider._READ_PERMISSION" />
...
</manifest>
```

If I try to resolve Content Provider in the same app, it works.

If I use `packageManager.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_PROVIDERS)` in my client code to get list of existing providers then for APIs [26,29] I can see my provider in the list. If I run this code in API 30 my provider is not in the list.

It seems that something was changed in API 30 related to registration of ContentProvider. However I can't find what.

Comment: Please show complete provider definition from manifest.

Comment: @blackapps, I've updated provider definition with my most recent changes

Comment: Isnt there a grand uri permission missing?

Comment: @blackapps, I've tried with uri permission, doesn't make any difference. Still works fine on device and doesn't on simulator.

Comment: You did not show the statement/code of app-2 that causes that exception.

Comment: How does app-2 know about the content provider of app-1?

Comment: You are not reacting. A pitty. I can confirm the problem as it happened to me a few days ago too. If you meanwhile found a solution or have other info then please tell us.

Comment: I am sorry for late respond. For the quick hack , I try to downgrade to API Level 29.

Comment: @blackapps, see my answer below, the question about app2 find content of app1 is not related to problem, it was never a problem in my application. The problem is Package Visibility in API 30, just adding one line ```queries``` made my ContentProvider work in all APIs again.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The reason my custom ContentProvider doesn't work on Emulator with API 30 is [Package visibility in Android 11+](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/package-visibility)

**To Fix** my issue I've added following `<queries>` element into client's AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest>
...
    <queries>
        <package android:name="com.a52.datafeeder01" />
    </queries>
...
</manifest>
```

where `com.a52.datafeeder01` is the package name where custom ContentProvider is defined.

Comment: +1 wasted a lot of time on wondering why my content provider works on real device by not on emulator. Just figured out, emulator is based on API 30 and this package visibility was causing problem. This is the correct solution but I have to replace package with provider tag.

Answer (score 12):

In case of my problem, simply add:

```
<manifest>
...
    <queries>
        <provider android:authorities="com.example.appcontainprovider" />
    </queries>
...
</manifest>
```

where `authorities` value is provider authorities.

Reference: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/package-visibility#provider-authority

Comment: This solution didn't work for me, the only solution that worked for me is giving the package name inside package tag like this 

 <queries>
        <package android:name="com.a52.datafeeder01" />
    </queries>

Can somebody please tell what is the difference in both of these approaches?

Answer (score 7):

Please add the following permission in manifest

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES"
                     tools:ignore="QueryAllPackagesPermission"/>
```

This resolved my problem in android 11

Comment: Thanks a Ton.. this working great

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES"
                     tools:ignore="QueryAllPackagesPermission"/>

Comment: Google Play restricts the use of high-risk or sensitive permissions, including the QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES permission, which gives visibility into the inventory of installed apps on a given device. For more details, you can read this article:
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10158779?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

From Android 11 , there are changes in package visibility. So need to add **queries** as below

https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility

```
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="yourPackage">
    <queries>
         <provider android:authorities="providerAuthority" />
    </queries>
    //Add your content provider's permission
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.permission" />
    <application ...../>
 </manifest>
```