# Android ContentResolver Unknown URL but ADB Shell command works fine

Tags: android, adb, android-contentresolver

I'm trying to run an insert command in an app to another app. I'm taking my ADB Shell command:

```
adb shell content insert --uri content://com.***.***/device_info --bind store_id:s:12345
```

Converting that to Java:

```
Uri contentUri = Uri.parse("content://com.***.***/device_info");
ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
contentValues.put("store_id", storeIdString);
mContext.getContentResolver().insert(contentUri, contentValues);
```

However when I run that Java code I get the following error:

```
Unknown URL content://com.***.***/device_info
```

But if I run that ADB Shell command I get no issues. The same problem happens if I try to query the same URI in code, while the same query via ADB shell command works perfectly fine

Comment: `to another app that has a content resolver. ` You mean: `to another app that has a content provider. `

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem.

As of Android SDK level 30, Content Providers have been limited via Package Visibility. Once I downgraded my app's SDK level to 28, it started working, but that introduced it's own set of problems.

Anyways I suggest trying out [some of these suggested solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63563995/failed-to-find-content-provider-in-api-30).